# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'QVariant'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, combo-box

> Type error :unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'QVariant'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ,line 260, in rac
> s=s+ar

Code :

```
def rac():
    cur_prov = self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentText()

    #calculate the amount of population in all provinces
    prov = layers[1].layer()
    s = 0
    for c in prov.getFeatures(): 
        st = st + c.attributes()[2]
   
    #calculate the amount of park's area
    park = layers[0].layer()   
    s = 0
    for p in park.getFeatures(): 
        ar = p.attributes()[6]
        s = s + ar
    rac = s / st
    self.dlg.textBrowser_2.setText(str(rac))
```

Comment: Voting to reopen because this question is likely to help future visitors, given that a good answer is here. The question itself could and should be improved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should skip the `NULL` values.

```
for p in park.getFeatures(): 
    ar = p.attributes()[6]
    
    if ar != NULL:
        s = s + ar

rac = s / st
```

Comment: I got this error:                                                                                                                                              
line 259, in rac
    ar=float(p.attributes()[6])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QVariant'

Comment: Is there any NULL value in the column 6?

Comment: Yes there are many NULL values

Comment: Then, you should skip the NULL values.

Comment: Thank you it works . The problem was in a line of the field area who has a string value who cannot be converted . Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6):

There are many things you can change about your code, but first your question.

The solution that Kadir proposes is very practical, it works for me in the console but not in the plugin, so I present you other alternatives.

**Evaluate if it is a QVariant**

Generally when you query the attributes of a field, it returns the data type of the field, either int, float or string, unless it is empty, so it returns an empty `QVariant`.

You can simply test to see if it is a `QVariant`

```
for p in park.getFeatures():
   ar = p.attributes()[6]
   if type(ar)!= QVariant:
        s = s + ar
```

Another option is the opposite, to evaluate if it gives a numerical value, but there are two conditionals:

```
for p in park.getFeatures():
   ar = p.attributes()[6]
   if type(ar)==int or type(ar)==float:
        s = s + ar
```

**Other aspects**

- You can consult the `QgsFeature` as a dictionary:

```
for p in park.getFeatures():
   ar = p[name of the field]
   if type(ar)!= QVariant:
        s = s + ar
```

- Compressing lists can make your code shorter and faster

```
lf=park.getFeatures()
list_values=[p[name of the field] for ar in lf   if type(ar)!= QVariant]
```

- For optimal performance in attribute queries you should apply `QgsFeatureRequest`:

For example, configure the request so that it does not return geometries, using less memory and faster.

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry )
lf=park.getFeatures(request)
list_values=[p[name of the field] for ar in lf   if type(ar)!= QVariant]
```